# How to use a global variable of str type to populate a MDLable text field. I also need to set font and size

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am ultimately trying to retrieve data from an API call to populate MDLabels.  I am new to Kivy so i hope my question is not to simple but i have not found a working example after hours of searching.

```
import kivy
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

#Global variable from a dictionary
orch_hostName = str("some text to add to a MDLabel")

class MyGui(Screen):
    orch_info = ObjectProperty(None)   
    def on_enter(self):
        orch_info1 = orch_hostName
        self.ids.orch_info.text = "orch_info1"

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Gray"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "300"
        
    
        return MyGui()
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()

##################################################
KV File
Widget:
<MyGui>
    orch_info: orch_info
    MDFloatLayout:
        MDLabel:
            id: orch_info
            multiline: True
            halign: 'left'
            markup: True
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            text_color: (105 / 255.0, 105 / 255.0, 105 / 255.0, 1)
            text: ""
            font_style: 'H1'
            pos_hint: {'x': .85, 'y': .47}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MyGui, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.orch_info.text = orch_hostName
    print(self.orch_info.text)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).